# Closing the jsp page based on user choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jsp page where if the user closes the page the popup box should appear asking whether he really wants to close the page.

If he chooses to close the page then i need to redirect to another jsp page using ajax.

How do i achieve the same.

I have a sample code which asks the user when he clicks the close button but this message is getting popped up when refresh,submit or clear buttons or any other buttons are pressed.

Can anyone sggest to modify the given code or any new functionality which achieves the same.

```
    sample.jsp
<html>
<head>
<title>Refresh a page in jQuery</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Stop a page from exit with jQuery</h1>

<button id="reload">Refresh a Page in jQuery</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#reload').click(function() {

        location.reload();

    });

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
        return '>>>>>Before You Go<<<<<<<< \n Your custom message go here';
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'Are you sure to leave';
});

$(window).bind('unload', function(){
  $.ajax({
      url:'some url',
      success:function(data){
          $("body").html(data);
      }

  })
})
```

you should unbind events before refresh

```
$('#reload').click(function() {
    $(window).unbind("beforeunload");
    $(window).unbind("unload");
    location.reload();

});
```